# ABAP: How to show transparent Image in cl_gui_custom_container?

Tags: image, transparency, gif, abap, dynpro

I would like to show a logo with transparency at the top of my dynpro custom container using the cl_gui_picture.

At the moment I am using the class cl_ssf_xsf_utilities to get an bmp out of the BDS.

The last step is the method load_picture_from_url from cl_gui_picture.

Is it possible to load an image like a gif or something with transparency?

Thanks! =)

Comment: What do you expect to appear in the background of the image?

Comment: I expect the background color from the underlying SAP GUI Theme to appear.

In the meantime I solved the problem by using the SAP Web Repository because it can handle GIF's with transparency.

I used the function module "DP_PUBLISH_WWW_URL" to get the url for "cl_gui_picture".

Comment: @fizzgig, so post the answer to your own question with the solution, so that everybody who faces this problem could receive help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I expect the background color from the underlying SAP GUI Theme to appear. In the meantime I solved the problem by using the SAP Web Repository because it can handle GIF's with transparency. I used the function module "DP_PUBLISH_WWW_URL" to get the url for "cl_gui_picture".